# Algebra clock problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An absent-minded watch repairman connected the hour hand to the minute hand pinion and the minute hand to the hour hand pinion and set the clock at 6AM which was the correct time then. How soon after 6AM (at what time) will this clock give the correct time again?

Comment: It does not matter which hand is connected to which pinion, so it will be 6:33 AM

Comment: @Vikram: How did you come up with that answer?

Comment: I don't see how it could be 06:33 and the pinion does matter as it will change the speed of the hand.

Comment: Sorry friends , my answer is wrong

Comment: I think the obvious (and possibly wrong) answer is 12 hrs. later at 6PM when both hands have made a circuit.

Comment: Of course, if he connected the hands wrong, the clock will not be showing a valid time, even at the initial time of 6:00. The reason is that if the hands were switched, the time would ostensibly be 12:30 -- but at 12:30, the hands are not on the "12" and the "6" because the hour hand would have advanced halfway between the "12" and the "1".

Comment: But it is showing a valid time at 06:00 because he sets it to the correct time (even though the hands move at the wrong speeds)

Comment: @oliveeuler: You're right after 12 hours it will display a correct time. But our professor, who gave this problem, said that there will be a time between those 12 hours when the clock will display a correct time.

Comment: I thought as much
(I get the feeling that modular arithmetic could help but I'm quite inexperienced with it)

Comment: Hint: use angular speed of pinions of the skewed watch, and the reference one. When the two minutes and/or hours (interesting to see the result for both - straightforward, remains to be seen) match, you have your time...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try writing out formulae for the positions of the hands on a correct clock and one the wrong clock in terms of time.

Correct clock:

the long hand is at $(\text{time in mins})\times (6^{\circ}), \mod 360^{\circ}$, since it starts straight up and moves by 360 degrees each hour;

the short hand is at $180^{\circ} +(\text{time in mins})\times \frac{1}{2}^{\circ}, \mod 360^{\circ}$, since it starts straight down and moves by 360 degrees every 12 hours.

Now write similar equations for the wrong clock, and look for values of time from which the long-hand equations give the same angle and so do the short hand equations.

Answer (score 0):

correct answer is 7:06 AM, in 1 hour and 6 minutes the  minute hand will rotate 360+30 plus degrees and just cross 7 o'clock and the hour hand will rotate 30 degrees and come to 6 minutes (right next to 1 o'clock)

Comment: mark position of both the hands in false clock after 1 hour and 6 minutes and see if you get the correct time.

Comment: In $1:06$ the minute hand travels $360+36=396$ degrees, while the hour hand travels $\frac {1.1}{12}\cdot 360=33$ degrees.

Comment: @RossMillikan, dosen't it coincide with 7:06 AM?

Comment: No, the minutes hand at $7:06AM$ is $39$ degrees from vertical, while on this clock the hour hand will be $33$ degrees from vertical.  Similarly the "hour" hand will be off by $6$ degrees the other way.

Comment: @RossMillikan, minute hand rotates 360 degrees in 60 min, so in 1 minute it rotates 360/60=6 degrees, so in 6 min it rotates 36 degrees, so difference of 3 degrees between this clock and normal one, Diff of 6 degrees changes the minute(6 to 7, 7 to 8 etc).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a phantom hour hand that starts at $6$ (just like the actual hour hand)
but is connected to the correct pinion so that it moves at the speed an hour hand is supposed to move.

The clock cannot be showing the correct time unless the actual hour hand is where it is supposed to be, namely, where the phantom hour hand is.

So we have two "hands" that start at one position on the clock (pointing to $6$);
one hand rotates at a rate of one revolution per hour, the other at a rate of
one revolution every $12$ hours. They are next at the same position when 
$\frac{12}{11}$ hours have passed, the same amount of time as it takes between noon and when the hands meet again on a normal clock.

So far, we know only that the hour hand is in the correct position at $\frac{1}{11}$ hour after $7$ AM. But what about the minute hand?

If the minute hand does not end up where it is supposed to be at $\frac{1}{11}$ hour after $7$ AM, you will have to look for a later time when the clock is correct.
So the next step is to find out whether or not the minute hand *will* be where it should be at that time.
There are various ways of doing this, including direct computation (since you know exactly when to look at the hand's position); I leave that step "as an exercise."